# convert pandas to_numeric with 'ignore' errors failing to convert strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to convert values of a serie to numeric using `pd.to_numeric` with errors:'ignore' because I also have some strings that I need to preserve. This should be very straight forward but for some reason pd.to_numeric fails to convert to numeric values. I am using pandas version 1.0.3.

[image]

I would have expected to leave the string as it is, convert `'1'` to a int and `'1.2'` to a float but it does not seem to be the case. Am I doing something wrong? is it a bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It working different, check [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

> If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

In another words if error it return not changed data.

close, what you need is convert with `errors='coerce'` and then replace missing values (all numeric are floats because at least one `float` and because NaNs are floats):

```
s = pd.Series(['apple','1','1.2',2])

print (pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').fillna(s))
0    apple
1        1
2      1.2
3        2
dtype: object
```

---

```
print (pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').fillna(s).map(type))
0      <class 'str'>
1    <class 'float'>
2    <class 'float'>
3    <class 'float'>
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I missinterpreted the documentation